# Erro a recriar nova chave ssh: gitconfig: Permission denied

Tags: git, ssh

No computador em que trabalho, existia outro usuário. Contudo tenho de criar uma nova chave ssh e um novo usuário.

Porem quando executo os comandos:

> $ git config --global user.name "alex jose silva"

Recebo a mensagem:

> error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/GNU/SSH/.gitconfig: Permission denied

Optei por apagar a pasta SSH do computador porémo erro persiste

> error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/GNU/SSH/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Comment: Tentou executar com o `terminal` em modo de administrador? O segundo erro é porque você apagou os arquivos.

Comment: Sim...recebo essa mensagem: Could not create directory '/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/SSH/.ssh': No such file or directory

Comment: Como eu disse anteriormente, esse erro **é porque você apagou os arquivos**. Restaure os arquivos e tente com o terminal/prompt no modo administrador. Ou altere o arquivo diretamente.

Comment: Não tem como restaurar os arquivos...

Comment: fiz uma nova instalação do git no zero

Comment: Já tentou reinstalar o software para ele restaurar os arquivos?

Comment: Já sim..porém sem sucesso

Comment: Optei agora para gerar a chave SSH

Comment: e criar novo usuario

Comment: e quando executo o comando: $ git config --global user.name "alex.jose.silva"

Comment: recebo essa mensagem: error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/SSH/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui corrigir a permissão da pasta. Optei então por reinstalar tudo novamente:

Logo apos tudo voltou a funcionar normalmente: Gerar a chave .ssh (é necessario cria uma pasta SSH dentro da GNU)e clonar o repositórios